# How to return all the rows in this SQL while

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

The question being wide enough, I haven't found the answer on the forums, or at least not entirely. Being accustomed to use arrays, and not finding it practical in the long run, I decided to put myself in programming object.

Here is my problem: When I run the SQL query below, I can't recover all of the lines that I should recovered. And I don't find how to do ...

```
public function testing($param) {

    $return = new stdClass();

    if ($request = $this->getConnexion()->prepare('SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table WHERE col1=?') or die(mysqli_error($this->getConnexion()))) {

        $request->bind_param('s', $param);
        $request->execute();
        $request->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3);
        $request->store_result();

        while($request->fetch()) {

            $return->col1 = $col1;
            $return->col2 = $col2;
            $return->col3 = $col3;

            /*
            Here's what I used to do before

            $return[] = array(
                'col1' => $col1,
                'col2' => $col2,
                'col3' => $col3
            );
            */

        }

        $request-> close();

        // Here : how to make it understand that I want all the lines and not a single
        return $return;

    } else {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php Or I am missing something? :)

Comment: `$r = new StdClass; $r->col1 = $col1;
            $r->col2 = $col2;
            $r->col3 = $col3; $return[] = $r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well `$return` is your stdClass object, so you're just overwriting the 3 properties on each iteration. Use an array of objects:

```
$return = array();

...
...

while($request->fetch()) {

    $item = new stdClass;
    $item->col1 = $col1;
    $item->col2 = $col2;
    $item->col3 = $col3;

    $return[] = $item;
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah. That's it ! It's about 2 hours I am looking for this. I had not thought to do that way. Thank you!